# Erro ao criar usuário admin Django 1.11

Tags: django

Estou a um tempo tentando criar um usuário *admin*, mas ele sempre me retorna o erro abaixo. O que pode está acontecendo?

Estou utilizando as seguintes configurações:

```
Ubuntu Server 14.04.5 LTS, 
Python 3.4.3, 
Django 1.11.
```

Qualquer ajuda será bem vinda.

```
Username (leave blank to use 'ubuntu'): ubuntu
Email address: ubuntu@gmail.com
Password:
Password (again):
```

> Traceback (most recent call last):   File
>   "/var/www/html/meusitedjango/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py",
>   line 65, in execute
>       return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)   File "/var/www/html/meusitedjango/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/db/backends/sqlite3/base.py",
>   line 328, in execute
>       return Database.Cursor.execute(self, query, params) sqlite3.OperationalError: attempt to write a readonly database
>       self.UserModel._default_manager.db_manager(database).create_superuser(**user_data)
>   File
>   "/var/www/html/meusitedjango/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/contrib/auth/models.py",
>   line 170, in create_superuser
>       return self._create_user(username, email, password, **extra_fields)   File "/var/www/html/meusitedjango/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/contrib/auth/models.py",
>   line 153, in _create_user
>       user.save(using=self._db)   File "/var/www/html/meusitedjango/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/contrib/auth/base_user.py",
>   line 80, in save
>       super(AbstractBaseUser, self).save(*args, **kwargs)   File "/var/www/html/meusitedjango/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/db/models/base.py",
>   line 806, in save
>       force_update=force_update, update_fields=update_fields)   File "/var/www/html/meusitedjango/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/db/models/base.py",
>   line 836, in save_base
>       updated = self._save_table(raw, cls, force_insert, force_update, using, update_fields)   File
>   "/var/www/html/meusitedjango/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/db/models/base.py",
>   line 922, in _save_table
>       result = self._do_insert(cls._base_manager, using, fields, update_pk, raw)   File
>   "/var/www/html/meusitedjango/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/db/models/base.py",
>   line 961, in _do_insert
>       using=using, raw=raw)   File "/var/www/html/meusitedjango/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/db/models/manager.py",
>   line 85, in manager_method
>       return getattr(self.get_queryset(), name)(*args, **kwargs)   File "/var/www/html/meusitedjango/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py",
>   line 1060, in _insert
>       return query.get_compiler(using=using).execute_sql(return_id)   File
>   "/var/www/html/meusitedjango/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/compiler.py",
>   line 1099, in execute_sql
>       cursor.execute(sql, params)   File "/var/www/html/meusitedjango/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py",
>   line 80, in execute
>       return super(CursorDebugWrapper, self).execute(sql, params)   File "/var/www/html/meusitedjango/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py",
>   line 65, in execute
>       return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)   File "/var/www/html/meusitedjango/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/db/utils.py",
>   line 94, in **exit**
>       six.reraise(dj_exc_type, dj_exc_value, traceback)   File "/var/www/html/meusitedjango/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/utils/six.py",
>   line 685, in reraise
>       raise value.with_traceback(tb)   File "/var/www/html/meusitedjango/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py",
>   line 65, in execute
>       return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)   File "/var/www/html/meusitedjango/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/db/backends/sqlite3/base.py",
>   line 328, in execute
>       return Database.Cursor.execute(self, query, params) django.db.utils.OperationalError: attempt to write a readonly database
>   (meusitedjango)
>   ubuntu@ubuntuserver:/var/www/html/meusitedjango/meusitedjango$

Answer (score 2):

me parece, pelo trecho:

```
"/var/www/html/meusitedjango/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/db/backends/sqlite3/base.py", line 328, in execute return Database.Cursor.execute(self, query, params) sqlite3.OperationalError: attempt to write a readonly database
```

Que o seu banco de dados está sendo usado em modo readyonly.

tente mudar o owner do diretório e do db para www-data

```
chown www-data:www-data /home/username/Django    
chown www-data:www-data /home/username/Django/db.sqlite
```

Comment: Muito obrigado!
Já tinha removido esse arquivo 0001_initial.py umas duas vezes.

A solução foi remover o arquivo  0001_initial.py gerado pelo migrate e depois rodar os comandos abaixo.

./manage.py migrate

python manage.py createsuperuser